# symfony2 sql query to queryBuilder or createQuery

Tags: php, sql, symfony, union, query-builder

How can I write my SQL query in Symfony2's query builder?

```
(
 SELECT t2.`year_defence`, 'advisor_id' AS col, t2.advisor_id AS val, COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM projects t2
 GROUP BY t2.`year_defence`, t2.advisor_id
) 
UNION 
(
 SELECT t2.`year_defence`, 'type_id' AS col, t2.type_id AS val, COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM projects t2
 GROUP BY t2.`year_defence`, t2.type_id
)
UNION
(
 SELECT t2.`year_defence`, 'technology_id' AS col, t2.technology_id AS val, COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM projects t2
 GROUP BY t2.`year_defence`, t2.technology_id
)
ORDER BY 1 , 2 , 3;
```

Doesn't work any possibilities which I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using:

```
$statement = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->executeQuery($sql);
$result    = $statement->fetchAll();
```

if you have just a static query.

Or if you have user inputs to validate use:

```
$connection = $this->entityManager->getConnection();
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT myvalues FROM mytable WHERE id = :id");
$statement->bindValue('id', 1);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Your right. If you want to have Entity objects, I suggest to separate these queries and do partial queries. You do need more queries though, but I think its the best way to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html ?